# Hide the overflow on a circular button

Tags: html, css

I tried some hover effects from [here](https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/) and I tried to put the radial out effect on to a circle (border-radius: 50%) but there is a rectangle showing up for a brief moment when you actually hover over the circle.

my code:

```css
button {
  background: #F0F1F2;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hvr-radial-out {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-radial-out:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098D1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-radial-out:hover, .hvr-radial-out:focus, .hvr-radial-out:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-radial-out:hover:before, .hvr-radial-out:focus:before, .hvr-radial-out:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<button class="hvr-radial-out">Test</button>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the rectangle, tested on Firefox 87.0 and Chrome 89.0.4389.114.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/gvz65d3n/7/ try this maybe

Comment: Same behaviour. You can increase the animation to let's say 3s, but still there is no rectangle

Comment: Yeah, there's no rectangle

Comment: @hcjanni, what browser, browser version and OS are you using?

Comment: OS High Sierra 10.13.6, Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116

Comment: I added a gif to my post

Answer (score 0):

When click the button, there is a square border. I guess that you want to remove it. So add `outline:0;`

```css
button {
  background: #F0F1F2;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 0;
}

.hvr-radial-out {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
   
}
.hvr-radial-out:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098D1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-radial-out:hover, .hvr-radial-out:focus, .hvr-radial-out:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-radial-out:hover:before, .hvr-radial-out:focus:before, .hvr-radial-out:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<button class="hvr-radial-out">Test</button>
```

Comment: Sry, my guess is wrong. but i didn't get an issue that you shown as a gif.

Comment: Update your browser version. sometimes it may solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of `border: none` property you have used on **button**
You are using both `border-radius: 50%;` and `border: 1px;` which might be contradicting each other.

Please try with having `border: 1px;`

Comment: Or may be you can check using `border-radius: 50%;` for `.hvr-radial-out:before`

Comment: @hcjanni
Can you please try using `border-radius: 50%;` for `.hvr-radial-out:before`